# Liquibase ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: maven, liquibase

I get this error message for just including liquibase as a dependency & having it enabled (default).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

> Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges [Failed SQL: (1031) CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR2(255), CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))]

I have an existing functioning DataSource & HikariConfig to an Oracle DB thru Kerberos Authentication. I am confused on how its trying to execute sql code... I haven't declared any `@LiquibaseDataSource` or even a changelog for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, just by adding liquibase dependency SB will auto-configure it with your existing DataSource. And on the first start of the application on an empty database Liquibase bean will try to execute the creation of it's two utility tables:

`DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` and `DATABASECHANGELOG`

So, user from your primary DataSource is being picked up by Liquibase, and probably doesn't have sufficient privileges to create tables on this schema. This is why you are seeing this message.

Comment: Yea your right, the user didn't have privileges to create tables. Do you know if it will attempt to do this for just the primary schema or any that are annotated with `@LiquibaseDataSource` ?

Comment: Not sure if I got your question correctly but Liquibase will create its own utility tables and execute any defined change sets onto the schema provided via data source. Now if you have just one DataSource it will use that one. If you want to have different configuration for connecting Liquibase to a db (either a user or even schema) you will create the `@LiquibaseDataSource` and by doing so Liquibase will use this connection instead of the primary DataSource.